# How to set Remember me function in angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11

I'm newer to angular. I want to write a Remember me function in my project.

Can I implement remember me function using only Front-end(Angular 11) Or Do I need back end also?

How I do that?

This is my auth.service.ts

```
   this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

    this.baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  }


  get token(): string | null {
    let auth: AuthResponse | string = localStorage.getItem('auth');

    if (!auth) {
      return null;
    }

    auth = JSON.parse(auth) as AuthResponse;

    return auth.token;
  }


  login(data) {
    return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}/user/authenticate`, data)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.configService.handleError),
        tap(() => window.location.reload()),
      );
  }


  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
  }
```

This is my login.ts

```
  onSubmitHandler(): void {
    this.loading = true;

    if (this.authForm.invalid) {     
      return;
    }
    
    this.authService.login(this.authForm.value)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(data));
        this.loading = false;              
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that something to handle on the server-side? What backend stack are you using, .NET Core? [`signinManager.SigninAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) has an option `isPersistent`

Comment: Yes .NET Core 3.1.